# tar on remote machine and save the compress file under specific folder

Tags: linux, ssh, tar, remote, compression

we want to tar the folder - `current` on remote machine  and save the compressed file under `/tmp`

so we do that:

```
ssh 18.23.2.12 "tar -zcvf current_bck.tar.gz /var/current -C /tmp"
```

but on remote machine the file saved under `/root` instead under `/tmp`

where we are wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you change the order of the arguments: `tar -C /tmp -zcvf current_bck.tar.gz /var/current`? Otherwise use `ssh 18.23.2.12 "cd /tmp && tar -zcvf current_bck.tar.gz /var/current"`

Comment: yes its put it under /tmp , but not so elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it saved to `/tmp`: `tar -f /tmp/name_of_file.tar ....`

Comment: In addition to this, the `-C` option only affects the pathnames  mentioned _after_ the option itself (and `-C` will not affect the pathname given by `-f`).